# Which continent should be to drain airmass from oceanic humid to dry?

Tags: climate

Or how quickly airmass drains over continent, if continent is plain? I know about rain shadow, but what if there are not mountains?

My planet is not rotating around its axis, and all airmass move from poles to equator.
Here is a map, if it helps.

[image]

[image: periods of rotation and suns]
[image: airmass circulation]

Comment: Welcome to Worldbuilding Dwarf, please take our [tour] and refer to the [help] for guidance. We'd need more details of your planet before being able to answer such as is it orbiting a star? (if not, then what drives circulation patterns and stops the whole thing freezing) What is its period of rotation? (if zero, then a day=a year) It might also help clarity if you were to make use of a translation program, just to help us communicate without misunderstanding. Enjoy the site.

Comment: hi @DwarfBormotun, that map looks great ! but I don't understand *"not rotating around itself axe, and all airmasses move from poles to equator"* you can't have permanent wind in one direction ? And why would airmasses start moving to the equator ? When there is no planetary rotation, no coriolis.. air pressure differences between different regions will be small.

Comment: @Goodies You're not quite right. Think of two conditions. (a) tidally locked (one rotation per orbit), same face to sun at all times. The higher altitudes of the atmosphere heat more than the lower altitudes, causing circultation. The sun-side heats but the oposite cools, causing rotation. This meets the OP's expecations. (b) No rotation at all, which means every side of the planet sees the sun once each year, that causes more complex circulation. Are they realistic? Possibly not, but what the OP's asking for isn't unreasonable. You don't need planetary rotation to get wind.

Comment: Hello Dwarf. You're asking a complex question despite the wonderfully simple conditions you've suggested. How much water vapor evaporates depends on the depth of the sea, currents, cloud cover, etc. How quickly it condenses to rain depends on how high up the moisture gets, the nature of the ground it overpasses, how dry that land was to begin with. In reality, sometimes a quick shower will occur. Sometimes a monsoonal downpour. Sometimes over a couple of acres, sometimes over half the continent. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi, guys. Thank you for comments. And thank you for correcting my post, I am not english speaking. 
So, I know, the question is not very accurate. If there is some unknowns founded, mean them earthlike. 
So we have: veeeeery long rotation period around its axe, almost not (may be it is not physically accurate, but I need for this assumption for my LoRe). And this planet have two suns, one of them have not strong influence on climate (brown dwarf), and another one is sunlike. I attached a new picture to root post.

Comment: @JoinJBHonCodidact, I whant to create humidity map to understand which biome where is )

Comment: Creating a humidity map would be, IMO, much simpler than answering the question in your post, which appears to ask about rainfall. You should update your post to ask for only that, if that is what you're seeking.

Comment: There is no easy answer. It depends on how far moist wind can travel. See how Gulf of Mexico sends humidity up the central US into Canada.

Comment: thank you all. 
So if this feature is sum of a lot of others, I can do what I whant ))) Because if there will any trouble in this feature, I can explain it by one of those foundation features )))))